# 17-08-2022 15:46:29 fromNow() is not showing the correct date

Tags: php, laravel, momentjs

I am using MomentJS to convert 17-08-2022 15:46:29 to a more readable format, like, **Just right now**, but it is showing in a wrong way, I mean, it should be showing **Just right now, or Two hours ago**, but it is showing **18 hours ago**

Let's see some blade+vuejs code:

```
                        fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                            moment.locale('pt-br');
                            var data = oData.created_at;
                            let criado = moment(data, "DD/MM/YYYY").fromNow();
                                $(nTd).html(criado);
                        }
                    },
```

And at the Model id do like:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($created_at)
    {
        return date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($created_at));
    }
```

It is running on a PHP Laravel app.
Any ideas?

Comment: In your PHP, you have the format "d-m-Y H:i:s", but in the JS, you have "DD/MM/YYYY"; those clearly don't mean the same thing. Although you haven't actually shown us how these two pieces of code relate to each other

Comment: obviously moment.js and your server think they are in different timezones.  Moment.js probably expects the time to be in UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks You guys! Because of your answers I have got what as missing:

```
                        fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                            moment.locale('pt-br');
                            var data = oData.created_at;
                            let criado = moment(data, "DD/MM/YYYY H:i:s").fromNow();
                                $(nTd).html(criado);
                        }
                    },
```

The params `H:i:s` was missing!

Thanks a lot for your help!